# Kitniyos within Chabad-Lubavitch

Tags: minhag, passover, chabad, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I was wondering what stance Chabad-Lubavitch holds regarding kitniyos. Do they follow the Ashkenazi minhag of not consuming kitniyos on Pesach, or do they follow the Sephardi minhag, which doesn't worry anything about it. Or maybe they have their own set of laws concerning it? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Do you know if Chabad-Lubavitch generally follows Ashkenazi or Sefardi customs? Do you suspect those in Chabad-Lubavitch don't just follow the practice of their respective ancestors?

Comment: Well they've had different minhagim before, ones that don't subscribe to Ashkenaz or Sephard...

Comment: Well, have you tried searching at all on the internet? Asking friends? Do you feel like you have the same doubt about any other Jewish law issue? Why or why not?

Comment: Chabad Rabbi Nachman Wilhelm discusses Kitniyot here: http://www.shturem.org/index.php?section=news&id=86938

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Google is your friend"

[The History, Rationale and Practice of Avoiding Kitniyos on Passover](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/871998/jewish/The-History-Rationale-and-Practice-of-Avoiding-Kitniyos-on-Passover.htm) has an explicit statement

> The Alter Rebbe, Rabbi Schneur Zalman of Liadi, specifically forbids
>   oils derived from kitniyos.

Thus this would imply that if even the derived oils are forbidden (which some may allow), then kal vachomer, the kitniyos themselves would be forbidden. That site goes into the details about kitniyos and the psakim from the past down to today.

From that posting. It would appear that Chabad follows the Ashkenazic minhag and forbids kitniyos.

@DoubleAA says that there are Sefardim who are Chabad and he has been to a Sefardi Chabad shul with a Chabad rabbi that maintained Chabad customs as well as Sfard.

Comment: They are absolutely strict on kitniyos from everything I've personally experienced.

Comment: Unless they are sefardim and keep there family tradition

Comment: If you look at the article you have linked to, you will see that it is discussing minhagim. The citation from the Alter Rebbe is addressing the subject of Ashkenazic minhag as it relates to the subject of oils derived from kitniyot. It is not about kitniyot in all circumstances. But this question is asking about the position of Chabad in regard to following minhag in general. There are Lubavitchers who follower Sephardic minhag in regard to kitniyot and those who follow a different minhag. Chabad, which corresponds to the 13th gate, the gate open to all, encompasses all approaches.

Comment: @YaacovDeane As I read the quote from the Alter Rebbe, he was talking about how **he** paskened about the oil, not how other ashkenazim paskened. Thus the inference as to what he held for kitniyos in general would apply. Unless the Chabad changed since then, it would still apply. This was the only part of the linked article that would indicate what Chabad Lubavitch specifically would say. The rest of the article implies that Chabad follows the Ashkenaz minhag but does not say so explicitly. However, other articles on different subjects do point out where the Chabad differ in their practices

Comment: @sabbahillel That's how he paskined _for ashkenazim_ (seemingly). There are Sefardim with Chabad philosophy. I've even been to a 100% Sefardi Chabad shul with a Chabad rabbi (they even Duchened on a random Shabbat in Chu"l).

Comment: @DoubleAA OK Thanks. I did not know that and I did not see that. I will add your comment to the answer.

Comment: I have also been to a number of Chabad shuls in Paris with sephardic rabbanim. They are Sephardim who became Chabad later in life but come from Northern Africa and hold a mix of sephardic and chabad customs. The same exists in Israel. We should also remember there was a Chabad *shaliach* in e.g., Morocco for dozens of years

Comment: @mbloch My case was a totally Ashkenazi Chabad rabbi who wound up in a far-flung community where he decided that running a Sefardi Shul would attract more people. So he changed his pronunciation and started up a totally Sefardi Shul where he gives his Divrei Torah based on the Rebbe.

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting! Chabad is definitely highly "customer-focused" and pragmatic. Kol hakavod to them !